# Limits of periodic box from pdb

Tags: visualization-software, vmd, pdb

I have a pdb file of some solvent molecules in a box of 20 Angstroms I have built using Tinker. I have opened the file with Chimera, Molden, Pymol and Avogadro... but I would like to see, and maybe generate a figure with, the proper limits of the box if there is any tool for doing so.

Has anyone succeded before? I do not mind getting used to another visualization program or tool.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I know VMD can show the box of surfaces, but I'm not sure about this specific case. Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pymol the cell [can be displayed](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Cell) by typing `show cell` into the command line.

Answer (score 6):

Atomic simulation environment is useful for a lot of other manipulations you might want to do and it comes with a [GUI](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/gui/gui.html) that is capable of doing this (given that you define the cell, it will also behave if you do not define a cell though since it works for periodic and non-periodic systems).

```
pip install --user ase
ase gui structure.pdb
```

[image: Visual of the GUI in Atomic Simulation Environment]